# Add new field to sub document in $Project stage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm selecting a document and want to modify inner sub document but show error

> { MongoError: can't add an expression for a subfield of lastCheckin
>   because there is already an expression that applies to the whole field

```
var req = { user : {id : ObjectId("5a03f9a0fafa645c8a39934c")}}
User.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            _id: ObjectId(req.user.id)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
         from: 'status',
         localField: 'lastCheckin._id',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'checkin'
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {    
            name:1,
            lastCheckin: { $arrayElemAt:[ "$checkin",0]},
            "lastCheckin.isLiked": {$literal:1}
        }
    },
])
.exec((err,results)=>{
    console.dir({
        err:err,
        results:JSON.stringify(results)
    });
})
```

while lastCheckin is either empty/null or

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a44e37fb746931a585dd62c"),
    likes: [ObjectId("5a44e37fb746931a585dd62c"), ...]
...
},
```

NOTE: $lookup works as expected, i'm getting lastChecin but i'm  not allowed to add isLiked key inside lastCheckin

Comment: Aggregates are more like Queries to find the data in collection, and i think you are trying to update your collection using aggregates?

Comment: no no i'm actually want to get a flag isLiked in my resposnse not want to save flag with document. i can do it by simple javascript but i want to do using mogno query

Comment: Can you show a sample document from the `status` collection?

Comment: there is only likes:[{
   type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref:"User"
  }] . in status schema noting else

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do the way you intended in 3.2 version.

You have to output all the projected fields from joined documents along with adding the new field.

Something like

```
{"$project":{
  "name":1,
  "lastCheckin":{
    "$let":{
      "vars":{"lastCheckin":{"$arrayElemAt":["$checkin",0]}},
      "in":{
        "otherfield1":"$$lastCheckin.otherfield1",
        "otherfield2":"$$lastCheckin.otherfield2", 
        "isLiked":{"$literal":1}
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

3.6 solution:

```
{"$project":{
  "name":1,
  "lastCheckin":{
    "$mergeObjects":[
      {"$arrayElemAt":["$checkin",0]},
      {"isLiked":{"$literal":1}}
    ]
  }
}}
```

3.4 solution

```
{"$project":{
  "name":1,
  "lastCheckin":{"$arrayElemAt":["$checkin",0]},
}},
{"$addFields":{"lastCheckin.isLiked":{"$literal":1}}}
```

Comment: I can also add the 3.4 solution if you like.

Comment: sure please add that may be helpful

Comment: Added both 3.4 and 3.6 solution. Consider upgrading to 3.6 which is the latest version.

Comment: in 3.4 you should just use $addFields as the next stage to add embedded field.